# Emacs technique for comparing sections of documents?

Tags: emacs, text, compare, regions

I'd like to be able to open two windows in Emacs, select a region of text in each window, and get a comparison of the difference between the two selections.

This would be very handy for a large-scale maintenance project, where I'm working on a version tree with multiple branches, lots of copy/paste, and code that is being moved around sporadically.

I've found a paid-for tool that does provide this function ([Ultracompare](http://www.ultraedit.com/products/ultracompare/tour/compare-files.html)), but it's windows-specific, and I need a solution that runs on Solaris/Linux.

Answer (score 36):

I think <kbd>M-x ediff-regions-wordwise</kbd> does what you want.

Run `ediff-regions-wordwise` and Emacs will prompt for each buffer, then prompt you to select (or confirm) a region in the buffer.

And, bonus, Emacs runs on Windows too!

Comment: That's nice, but could you tell, how do I finally see the differences? It just showed two windows with my selections, and one for entering a commands. From the list of a commands it is absolutely unclear how to use it.

Answer (score 9):

I'd be inclined to use `narrow-to-region` (C-x n n) in both buffers followed by `M-x compare-windows` if only because it has worked for me for at least 100 years. :-)